# Vw jetta 15 intermittent start

Tags: starting, vw

I've been having this issue with my car. The car doesn't want to start after I drive it and let it sit for 45 mins to an hour 30 mins. It cranks it just the last push to start driving, that doesn't want too. there is no check engine lights I took it to the dealer, ran a diagnostic and told me it might be the camshaft sensor, had to pay to get it replaced, but is not I still have the same problem. If I let it sit for 3 hours it will run again. Seriously frustrated. Bought this car last may, had to replace the ignition because car key was getting stucked and now this. Any help please, and thanks in advance. the car has 85k I bought it with 79k. Is a vw jetta 15 s model.

Comment: I don't know what part is causing your car to not run, or how to find it. But the symptoms you describe are a heat-related failure: some electrical component operates correctly when the motor is cold, and eventually fails when the motor warms up. Because the motor runs OK until you turn it off, and then will not restart, I think this mystery component has something to do with the machinery (starter motor?) or circuits (starter relay or wiring?) which allow the car to crank and start.

Comment: I doubt it would run without the cam sensor, and it would throw a code.  But the *crankshaft* sensor is a different story.  This is the exact same symptoms for older Jeeps, and the solution is a new crank sensor.  In any case, these things can be tested before you spend money to replace them.

Comment: Coolant temp sender would be a possibility - it would fit with the difficulty only occurring in a certain window after driving it.